# jQuery dynamic selector

Tags: jquery

I have some code which uses a selector in a loop.

This works:

```
document.getElementById("new_grouping_"+i).value
```

This does not: `$("#new_grouping_"+i).value`

Is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use the [val()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) function:

```
var myValue = $("#new_grouping_"+i).val(); // to get the value

$("#new_grouping_"+i).val("something");    // to set the value
```

Answer (score 12):

`$("#new_grouping_"+i).val()` gets you the value of a form.
`$("#new_grouping_"+i).text()` gets you the text of an html element.
`$("#new_grouping_"+i).html()` gets you the html of an html element.

`$("#new_grouping_"+i).val('value')` sets the value of a form.
`$("#new_grouping_"+i).text('value')` sets the text of an html element.
`$("#new_grouping_"+i).html('value')` sets the html of an html element.

`$("#new_grouping_"+i).append('value')` prepends something at the beginning of an element
`$("#new_grouping_"+i).append('value')` appends something at end of an element

`$("#new_grouping_"+i).before('value')` places something before an element
`$("#new_grouping_"+i).after('value')` places something after an element.

See More: [jQuery Manipulation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation)

Comment: Firefox gives me: "$("#new_grouping_desc_"+i).value is not a function" when I add the empty paren after value

Comment: Updated*. Was two letter off of the actual function.

Answer (score 2):

# is important for selector. Here I am setting value to span.

```
var i="spanId";
$("#"+ i).html("hello").show();
```