# jQuery Incorporating a variable within a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried adding a variable within the selector, but no dice.  I've tried a couple of different ways.

Ex1:

```
function makeDerp() {

  var num = 1;

  $("myDiv" + num).append("<h1>derp</h1>");

}
```

Ex2:

```
function makeDerp() {

  var num = 1;

  var thing = $("myDiv" + num);

  thing.append("<h1>derp</h1>");

}
```

Ex3:

```
function makeDerp() {

  var num = 1;

  var thing = "$('myDiv" + num + "')";

  thing.append("<h1>derp</h1>");

}
```

On all 3, I get nada.  Any ideas?  Something with my syntax or am I missing a step?

Comment: Here is a link that I found that may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230753/jquery-dynamic-selector

Comment: Did you make sure to include the jQuery library? What errors, if any show up in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first and second examples will work fine. The problem is your selector, which is currently looking for an element of type `myDiv`. I'm guessing you meant it to be an [`id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (perhaps a class selector, or something else entirely, but the idea is the same):

```
$("#myDiv" + num).append("<h1>derp</h1>");
```

Your third example will not work. `thing` contains a string literal, and that won't have an `append` method so you'll get a TypeError.

Comment: Yeah, I have the `#` in my production model, but it's not just doing anything.  Have to double check for typos.

Comment: @TimPlummer: Is `myDiv` an ID or a class?  If it's a class, use `.` instead of `#`.

Comment: @TimPlummer - Assuming the element you are trying to select actually exists, this will work fine. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2fCeB/

Comment: @Rocket `ID`  I've got that in my production code, but when I try, it just doesn't do anything.  So I can add the `var` within the selector without having to call on another `var` that assembles it beforehand?

Comment: @TimPlummer: "var within the selector without having to call on another var". Huh?

Comment: @Rocket - I can put the `var` right within the selector bracket?

Comment: @TimPlummer: `var num = 1; $("#myDiv" + num).append();`.

Comment: @Rocket - That's not working.  If I take out `num`, everything works like it should, except it just keeps adding the `<h1>` tag to the first `#myDiv` that it sees.

Comment: @Rocket - Yes, http://jsfiddle.net/2fCeB/12/  This is my actual production model.  I know what's in the question works, but no idea why it won't work inside an the `$.ajax()`.

Comment: @Rocket - I changed the URL to match what jsfiddle lets you do to simulate an AJAX call.

Comment: No, that's what it was originally.  You changed it back.  The only other error I found that the selector for the AJAX function was not set to `$(#part" + pn)`  But, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TimPlummer: Your AJAX call isn't correct, take a look at the [jsFiddle docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html).

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using either a class or id selector, in which case you're missing said symbol. Try:

```
$('#myDiv' + num);
```